# Disabling HTML output of query

Tags: cfml

I've created a form (in ColdFusion) that submits a value into a database, and afterwards shows the inserted value. The problem is that when a user, or hacker inserts a HTML tag or javascript tag, ColdFusion will also show that as an output value.

I know that there are ways to filter the special characters on submit with CFset, but i don't want to use that method. So not anything like this:

```
<cfset cleanmessage = ReReplace(getmessages.message, "[^\w]*", "", "ALL")>
```

Is there any other method to *only* filter the special characters (<@#!$%^*(&>) when showing the output?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you don't want to use those typical methods of stripping HTML/JS code and special characters? Also, there are numerous functions on http://cflib.org that take care of this so you don't have to "reinvent the wheel".

Comment: When using that, apparantly my css is getting ignored by the output. And it shows http://d.pr/i/q9Qn instead of http://d.pr/i/tFw2.

Comment: If your just looking to disable the content, When inserting your data into the DB, use #htmleditformat(message)# and that will nullify some of your special characters.

Comment: If your form includes a richtextarea it gets a bit more complicated because you will want to preserve some html tags.  There is a function called safetext() at cflib.org that will help with this situation.

Comment: Thanks for the help! the HTMLeditformat did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do these two things (at least) to sanitize user input:

1. Sanitize the data for SQL by using `<cfqueryparam ... >`. This prevents SQL injection attacks by escaping special SQL characters and sequences.
2. Sanitize the data when displaying it by using `HTMLEditFormat()`. This prevents various client-side vulnerabilities by escaping special HTML characters.

If you'd like to take your security a step further, [Portcullis](http://portcullis.riaforge.org/) looks like a great solution (I haven't used it myself though).

Regarding the use of `<cfset ... >`: You can use functions like `HTMLEditFormat()` without using `cfset`. Instead of creating a new variable to store the result of the function, just display the result as you call the function, like so: `<cfoutput>#HTMLEditFormat(data)#</cfoutput>`

Comment: query parameters do a lot of good things but escaping html is not one of them.

Comment: @DanBracuk Good point. I only mention it because the question relates to the safe handling of user-supplied data.